# How do I draw a percentage from baseline?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm looking to draw a simple line chart based off of each data point's distance from the mean. (% above, below, etc). I'm modeling it off of [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/c69f5960c6b1a95b6f78)

The two problems that I can't seem to figure out-
Why isn't my line drawing? I've been through each line and can't seem to figure it out.

Secondly, How do I take out the off- scaling on the y-axis? None of the scalings seems to be abnormal and I can't fix it. I assume it has to do with the scaling.

```
var x = d3.time.scale()
.range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.log()
.range([height, 0]);

  x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.ratio; }));
```

[Here's my CodePen](https://codepen.io/lahesty/pen/pOgbwe?editors=1111)

What might I be missing? I assume it's something I just haven't learned about d3 yet. Thanks so much!!

Comment: your xAxis is a string and is not a javascript Date() instance. first fix this. if your data is rendering from backend, send it in unix time and in your code convert it. first fix this then we move forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three problems in the code, regarding the path:

1. The parser is named `parseDate`, not `parseTime`;
2. You have to parse the string first and only then passing it to the `x` scale, not the other way around:

   ```
   line.x(function(d) { return x(parseDate(d.date)); });
   ```
3. You have to parse the strings to set the domain:

   ```
   x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return parseDate(d.date); }));
   ```

Here is the updated CodePen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qMbRoQ?editors=0011

And here a running snippet:

```js
var data = [{
    "date": "2018-08-22T14:53:37.267Z",
    "value": 2200000
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-08-21T14:53:37.267Z",
    "value": 7400000
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-08-20T14:53:37.267Z",
    "value": 9500000
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-08-19T14:53:37.267Z",
    "value": 9700000
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-08-18T14:53:37.267Z",
    "value": 7100000
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-08-17T14:53:37.267Z",
    "value": 4300000
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-08-16T14:53:37.267Z",
    "value": 2500000
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-08-15T14:53:37.267Z",
    "value": 2000000
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-08-14T14:53:37.267Z",
    "value": 6400000
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-08-13T14:53:37.267Z",
    "value": 9500000
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-08-12T14:53:37.267Z",
    "value": 100000
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-08-11T14:53:37.267Z",
    "value": 4800000
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-08-10T14:53:37.267Z",
    "value": 1400000
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-08-09T14:53:37.267Z",
    "value": 6100000
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-08-08T14:53:37.267Z",
    "value": 4400000
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-08-07T14:53:37.267Z",
    "value": 7000000
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-08-06T14:53:37.267Z",
    "value": 6100000
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-08-05T14:53:37.267Z",
    "value": 300000
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-08-04T14:53:37.267Z",
    "value": 2900000
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-08-03T14:53:37.268Z",
    "value": 2000000
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-08-02T14:53:37.268Z",
    "value": 300000
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-08-01T14:53:37.268Z",
    "value": 800000
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-07-31T14:53:37.268Z",
    "value": 1200000
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-07-30T14:53:37.268Z",
    "value": 9000000
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-07-29T14:53:37.268Z",
    "value": 8600000
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-07-28T14:53:37.268Z",
    "value": 6900000
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-07-27T14:53:37.268Z",
    "value": 3400000
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-07-26T14:53:37.268Z",
    "value": 8100000
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-07-25T14:53:37.268Z",
    "value": 2900000
  },
  {
    "date": "2018-07-24T14:53:37.268Z",
    "value": 6400000
  }
]

var margin = {
    top: 30,
    right: 30,
    bottom: 40,
    left: 50
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var formatPercent = d3.format("+.0%"),
  formatChange = function(x) {
    return formatPercent(x - 1);
  },
  parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ").parse;
// var parseTime = d3.time.Parse("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ");


var x = d3.time.scale()
  .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.log()
  .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .tickSize(-width, 0)
  .tickFormat(formatChange);

var line = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x(parseDate(d.date));
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.ratio);
  });

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var gX = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");

var gY = svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis axis--y");

gY.append("text")
  .attr("class", "axis-title")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .text("Change in Price");

var baseValue = +data[6].value;
console.log(baseValue)

data.forEach(function(d) {

  d.date = d.date;
  console.log(d.date)
  d.ratio = d.value / baseValue;
  console.log(d.ratio)
});


// Compute price relative to base value (hypothetical purchase price).


x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
  return parseDate(d.date);
}));
y.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) {
  return d.ratio;
}));

// Use a second linear scale for ticks.
yAxis.tickValues(d3.scale.linear()
  .domain(y.domain())
  .ticks(9));

gX.call(xAxis);

gY.call(yAxis)
  .selectAll(".tick")
  .classed("tick--one", function(d) {
    return Math.abs(d - 1) < 1e-6;
  });

svg.append("path")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", line);
```

```css
.axis {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

.axis-title {
  text-anchor: end;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis--x path {
  display: none;
}

.axis--y .tick:not(.tick--one) line {
  stroke-opacity: .15;
}

.line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
  stroke-linejoin: round;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

---

PS: Regarding the baseline issue, which is not clear, I suggest you post a new question, with the relevant explanation: it's always a good practice keeping **one problem** per question here at S.O.

Comment: Thanks for the **P.S**. I forked a codepen with the parse `date` change but just wasn't sure about the second question i.e. baseline. I'll make sure I too follow the practice of answering one problem per question and not just keep blabbering answers. :)