# Drawing a line in d3 error

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

There seems to be a bug in my d3 (version 4) code and I can't quite figure out why my line won't draw. My axes are there but my line path won't compute. I thought it was an issue with my data types (right now they're all numbers) But I must be missing something. Can you help me find what it is?

[Here is the codepen](https://codepen.io/lahesty/pen/mGEoMj?editors=1111)

Here are some key parts:

```
var line = d3.line()
.x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.y(function(d) { return y(d.ratio); });

g.append("path")
.datum(data)
.attr("fill", "none")
.attr("stroke", "steelblue")
.attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
.attr("d", line);
```

Structuring my data:

```
var baseValue = +data[0].avg_water_temp;

data.forEach(function(d) {
  d.date = d.date;
  d.ratio = +(d.avg_water_temp /baseValue);
});
```

Just an fyi, The y axis is actually a distance from a base Value, not distance from 0. So my ratios (y values) will be percentages.
[Like This](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/c69f5960c6b1a95b6f78)(without the log scale)

Thanks!! Let me know if there's anything I can clarify.

Comment: You need to parse the date string to a real `Date`

Comment: As @rioV8 notes, you are using strings to create a scale. Looking at the path data we see: `d="MNaN,188LNaN,63LNaN,0LNaN,250LNaN,188"` which indicates an issue with the x scale/x values. Should work if you parse dates eg: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NLrmrx?editors=1111

Comment: I'm not understanding this question: I already showed you that you have to parse the date strings in [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52014074/5768908), which by the way you didn't comment or acknowledge.

Comment: @GerardoFurtado my apologies I thought I had but that post slipped my mind! Done. I guess it needed reinforcement. Thanks so much for your help!